# join for two subquery select statement does't work

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to join two select statements/queries, in order to get a dataset combining the results. Both of the queries work well separately, but when I try to combine them using join, error occurs.*Error: Syntax error at or near "select" at line 10, position 1.* Can someone help me plz, thx!

```
select * from
(
  select dt, count(*) over (order by dt asc) as cumuA from
     (Select date_trunc('week',block_time) AS dt,"from" as sender 
     FROM data where "to" = 'xxxx') 
   as AAA

join 

    Select dt, count(*) over (order by dt asc) as cumuB from ( 
      Select min(date_trunc('week',block_time)) dt, "from" as sender from data where "to" = 'xxxx'
       group by sender)
    as BBB

ON AAA.dt = BBB.dt
)
```

Comment: What results are you expecting?  It looks like you are trying to use a JOIN where you want a UNION.

Comment: Which dbms are you actually using? (MySQL, MS SQL Server or Postgresql?)

Comment: `join select...` should be `... as AAA join (select ...) as BBB ON ...`

Comment: The `select * from` after the join doesn't make sense.    you just need the select in ()'s before the as BBB

Comment: I am using pgsql

Answer (score 0):

I'm not looking at what the query actually does or if there's a better way: simply addressing the reported error.

```
SELECT * FROM   --<This is unnecessary as well.
(
SELECT * 
 FROM (SELECT dt, count(*) over (order by dt asc) as cumuA 
       FROM (SELECT date_trunc('week',block_time) AS dt,"from" as sender 
             FROM data 
             WHERE "to" = 'xxxx'
            ) as aa
      ) as AAA
join 

SELECT * FROM --< this line makes no sense.  One need not select again after the join. the inline view BBB is sufficient. and the select is just a syntax error.  

(SELECT dt, count(*) over (order by dt asc) as cumuB 
      FROM (SELECT min(date_trunc('week',block_time)) dt, "from" as sender 
            FROM data 
            WHERE "to" = 'xxxx'
            GROUP BY sender
           ) AS bb
      ) as BBB

  ON AAA.dt = BBB.dt
)
```

I think you need it to be:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT dt, count(*) over (order by dt asc) as cumuA 
      FROM (SELECT date_trunc('week',block_time) AS dt,"from" as sender 
            FROM data 
            WHERE "to" = 'xxxx'
           ) as aa
     ) as AAA
INNER JOIN  
    (SELECT dt, count(*) over (order by dt asc) as cumuB 
     FROM (SELECT min(date_trunc('week',block_time)) dt, "from" as sender 
           FROM data 
           WHERE "to" = 'xxxx'
           GROUP BY sender
          ) AS bb
     ) as BBB
  ON AAA.dt = BBB.dt
```

Comment: thx for your help, sir. I changed my code as you suggested. But it still doesn't work. I improved my code per your suggestions as above. Any ideas? many thanks!

Comment: @Julian updated I believe there to be two selects not needed not just the 1 i had identified.